# Botframework Speak Feature inside Android WebView

Tags: android, node.js, webview, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am loading a bot URL inside an android application WebView. I have recently added speak feature in my bot, I have tried and tested it in Native Browsers - it works perfectly fine (except Safari and iOS chrome).

But when I am trying to use the same feature inside a WebView, the Microphone icon itself is not coming and nothing is spoken by the bot.

P.S., I am using DirectLine along with **.BrowserSpeechRecognizer()** and **.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer()**

Do I need to add anything extra to enable the speech feature in Android? I have given the necessary permissions required to use Microphone to my application.

Comment: Could you please add some code, both from the location in your app where you use `.BrowserSpeechRecognizer()` and `.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer()` and the portion of your bot that sends out that activity.

Comment: @MarkB hey Mark figured it out. According to this link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487255 support for Web Speech API in Android WebView is not there till date, that is the main problem. I need to find some other way around :/